# Facing issues while installing postgresql in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu-18.04, postgresql-9.5

I want to install postgresql in ubuntu but facing lot of issues,searched a lot but still no success,so when I try to install I used below commands:

```
sudo su -
apt-get install postgresql-9.5
update-rc.d postgresql enable
```

When the installation completes it gives me the error of

```
9.5 main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log
```

and after when I give following command

```
sudo -i -u postgres
psql
```

it gives me

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Unrelated: Any particular reason for installing such an old PostreSQL version?

Comment: You didn't start Postgres: `service postgresql start`

Comment: @JimJones well i was installing 12 version but just for checking I tried 9.5

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have started the service but still no success

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you need to connect as a specific user called postgres.

Try doing this : `sudo -i -u postgres` and then use `psql`